# Convert UIImage to 4 bits color space

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uiimage, color-space

I want to make my image as smaller as possible (in terms of data size, not changing height or width) and I can do it at expense of colors. So I want to have 4bit color scheme. How can I convert image to this color scheme? How can I create it? I start with trying to convert to grayscale with this code:

```
func convert(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let imageSize = image.size
    let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(imageSize.width), height: Int(imageSize.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!
    context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imageSize))
    //image.draw(in: )
    let imgRef = context.makeImage()
    return UIImage(cgImage: imgRef!)
}
```

and it's working. Now I want to modify it to use different color space. I found that what I am looking for is probably indexed color scheme, right? But I can't find any useful tutorial of how can I do this. I started like this:

```
    let table: [UInt8] = [0,0,0, 255,0,0, 0,0,255, 0,255,0,
                          255,255,0, 255,0,255, 0,255,255, 255,255,255]
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(indexedBaseSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                  last: table.count - 1, colorTable: table)!
```

But I am not sure if I started ok and should I continue. Which values should I then use in CGContext init method and so on. Can someone helps me? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this statement is useful here: "Note that indexed color spaces are not supported for bitmap graphics contexts."

Comment: So if I want to use some colors (not grayscale) smallest is generic RGB color space? And I can't get smaller image size?

Comment: You can. Maybe go through ciimage